# How to export posts with featured image

Tags: posts

How do I export only posts that have a featured image?

I only want to export posts.

Answer (score 3):

There's not an easy way to modify the export query that runs under `/wp-admin/export.php`.

It doesn't use the `WP_Query` or the `get_posts()` wrapper, instead it currently uses this query:

```
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} $join WHERE $where" );
```

without explicit filters to it, though it's possible to filter few settings through the `export_args` filter.

In ticket [#28146](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28146) it's suggested to rewrite it using `get_posts()` instead, but it's not currently active.

### Workaround

Here's one type of a **hack** to only export posts with a *featured image*:

[image: export items with featured image]

Here are the main parts for such a plugin:

### Step # 1

First we add the HTML for our filter's settings:

```
/**
 * Custom Export Filters
 */
add_action( 'export_filters', function() { 
?>
  <p><ul class="wpse-export-filters">
      <li>
        <label><?php esc_html_e( 'With a featured image:', 'mydomain' ); ?></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="wpse_with_featured_image" value="1">
      </li>
    </ul></p>
<?php 
} );
```

### Step #2

Next we hook into `export_wp` to modify the export process:

```
/**
 * Modify the export query
 */
add_action( 'export_wp', function( Array $args )
{   
    // User input
    $with_featured_image = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'wpse_with_featured_image' );

    // Check if we should activate our custom filter
    if( wp_validate_boolean( $with_featured_image ) )
        add_filter( 'query', 'wpse_modify_export' );

    return $args;
} );
```

where the `wpse_modify_export()` callback is defined as:

```
/**
 * Inject sub-query to find posts with featured image
 */
function wpse_modify_export( $query ) 
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Target the next posts query
    if( false === strpos( $query, "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}" ) )
        return $query;

    // Remove filter callback
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Inject sub-query to find posts with featured image
    $sql = " {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN ( SELECT DISTINCT post_id 
           FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm WHERE pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' ) AND ";

    return str_replace( ' WHERE ', ' WHERE ' . $sql, $query );          
}
```

Hope you can adjust this to your needs.

Comment: Ps: We could also use a similar approach to override the whole export query with a `WP_Query` generated request so that `export_args` become input arguments for `WP_Query`. We would then need to rewrite the old argument accordingly. We might also want to avoid the `WP_Query` to run, there are some tricks to do that.